# MissingMethodException when no reflection used

Tags: c#, .net

I have following class

```
public class Value
  {
    ...
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
  }
```

it is defined in assembly that is referenced by main module. In main module, there is simple code

```
private void SaveData()
 {
   Value value = GetValue();

   //some code here
   Results.Add(new Result
   {
     Unit = (int)value.Unit,
   });
 }
```

on entering SaveData method, i get MissingMethod exception. Execution of SaveData even not starts. Below is exception msg

> Method not found: 'Unit Value.get_Unit()'.

How can that happen? I don't use reflection at all, so where from this exception comes?
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I suspect you somehow compiled against a different version of the library than you loaded.

Comment: Both assemblies in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you added the `Value.Unit` member at one point, but you are running the assembly containing the `SaveData()` method against an older version of this other assembly, from before it contained this method.  The runtime is therefore expecting a method to exist, but it does not.  This is causing JIT-compilation of `SaveData()` to fail, which prevents it from being executed at all.

Double-check that all of the assemblies being used by this application are up to date with your latest build.

Comment: i've looked in object explorer methods of referenced assembly - get method present, and also I have tried to rebuild and update references. problem still exists

Comment: Have you opened the exact assembly that the program is using?  Try dumping out the paths to all of the loaded assemblies in your program at runtime (make sure you do this after referencing some type in this other assembly to force the runtime to load it).

Comment: i deleted references, made clean up and reloading of solution, and then added references again. After that all works